# SonarQube integration with gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, sonarqube

I am integrating Sonar qube with gradle. I have mentioned plugin and required properties in app level build.gradle file.But command execution failed with exception. Please clarify what else required?

Build.gradle :

```
        plugins {
                id "org.sonarqube" version "2.6.1"
                }
      sonarqube {
                properties {
                property "sonar.host.url", "http://192.168.22.12:9000/"
                property "sonar.projectName", "ourValues-Android"
                property "sonar.projectKey", "1234567"
                property "sonar.projectVersion","8.0"
                property "sonar.sources","src/main/java"
                property "sonar.exclusions","build/**,**/*.png"
                property "sonar.sourceEncoding", "UTF-8"
                property "sonar.report.export.path", "sonar-report.json"
                property "sonar.issuesReport.json.enable", "true"
                property "sonar.import_unknown_files", true
                property "sonar.android.lint.report", "./build/outputs/lint-
                results.xml"
                }
              }
```

Exception is when running command **gradlew sonarqube** :

> Execution failed for task ':app:sonarqube'.
>   You must define the following mandatory properties for 'Unknown': sonar.projectKey, sonar.sources

Please check the structure of project...

[image: Structure Of Project]

Comment: Are you following the  [Sample](https://github.com/sogilis/sonarqube-for-android-example)?

Comment: `Execute gradle sonarqube and wait until the build has completed, then open the web page indicated at the bottom of the console output. You should now be able to browse the analysis results.`

Comment: did you try that before? it's just for have knowledge about if there are others properties.

Comment: @KenrySanchez : Executing the command but build was failed with exception.

Comment: is this `Execution failed for task ':app:sonarqube'. You must define the following mandatory properties for 'Unknown': sonar.projectKey, sonar.sources`?

Comment: i'm not sure but try `org.sonarqube:1234567` with `org.sonarqube`

Comment: `property "sonar.projectKey", "org.sonarqube:1234567"`

Comment: `src/main/java/*` with `sonar.sources`

Comment: @KenrySanchez : Tried but not working.

Comment: the same error??

Comment: try with property `"sonar.sources","src"`

Comment: `property "sonar.projectKey", "my-project-example"`

Comment: I suggest you create a sonar-project.properties for your android project. Maybe, with that, you'll have a better management with your keys. Please, tell me if my recommendations work.

Comment: @KenrySanchez : Tried but no progress :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163496/discussion-between-kenry-sanchez-and-anshika-bansal).

Comment: I guess the problem come from the module hierarchy of your project. Properties should be defined in the root module and will be inherited for each submodule. I know you can have fancy project structure with Gradle so maybe we are not covering your case. The best would be for you to share your project structure (=all Gradle config files, you can remove all source code).

Comment: Check here https://sonarqube4android.wordpress.com/2018/01/19/have-code-quality-review-on-your-android-project/

Comment: @JulienH.-SonarSourceTeam : Please check the screenshot for project structure.

Comment: Where have you added the SonarQube configuration? In the root build.gradle or in the app/ only? Any chance you can share a reproducer?

Comment: @JulienH.-SonarSourceTeam : In app level only. In project level i added scanner plugin i. e classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.2"

Comment: Maybe try to move the configuration to the root `build.gradle`